# Hong Kong Dollar Options

Tags: options, currency, volatility, hong-kong

I would like to bet on a de-pegging of the Hong Kong Dollar from the USD. Even though the volatility is perfect for an options trade, it seems hard to find any for the retail investor.
Is anyone aware of some options on the Hong Kong Dollar?
Thanks

Comment: None in Exchange. Possible via OTC. You may also short spot USDHKD and pay 1.5% interest per year, but this is not an Option.

Comment: The lovely thing about the option in my opinion is that one can 'only' lose 100%, instead of much more with a leveraged short USDHKD in the case if something goes terribly wrong. Do you have any idea on what the minimum investment is with such OTC options?

Comment: Minimum investment on OTC? I have two answers, first, if you have to ask, you can't afford it. Second is OTC, in other words, whatever the heck the Sales feels like. But I can assure you there will be a bank willing to make the option on OTC. I can also assure you that this will never be on an exchange (or as we call it FLOW/Vanilla, the name should suggest why not).